# Falling rain effect on hair particles

Tags: particles

I was trying to create a rain effect on grass where droplets of rain slowly slide from top to bottom of a grass stalk.So I added a plane created a vertex group and added hair particles,did some other tweaking then added another emitter object that acts a rain emitter.But the problem is the hair particles do not seem to respond to the falling droplets/particles from other plane.So,if you guys have any idea about how to achieve it any help would be appreciated.Thanks.